# Actual run time of Spark job from context

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get the time an application spends in the state `RUNNING`. This can be easily done if a [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html) is used by adding [SparkAppHandle.Listener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkAppHandle.Listener.html) callbacks and listen to the `stateChanged` event.

Long story short, I don't have the option to use [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html) but I need to know the actual runtime of an application (without the time it spends in the `WAITING` state).

Can this information be gleaned from the `SparkContext`? [SparkListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener.html) doesn't seem to provide a callback for application state change. The actual duration cannot be worked out from `onApplicationStart` and `onApplicationEnd` because `onApplicationStart` fires when the application starts waiting.

I'm also aware of [QueryExecutionListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/util/QueryExecutionListener.html) but the individual jobs also include the `WAITING` period (`onSuccess` callback duration param).

Edit: Upon further inspection, `SparkAppHandle.Listener` doesn't seem to be able to do this either.